# Visual Studio xaml editor for Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resourcedictionary

Does anyone else think its a bit lame that opening the xaml for a resource dictionary defaults to a split screen for Design and Xaml?

Is there a setting I am missing? Or is this just MS' way of telling me to buy Blend...

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this really bothers you, there is a setting under Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous, that reads 'Always open documents in full XAML view'. Obviously this will also open your forms in full XAML view.

Apart from that, I don't think VS is smart enough to distinguish between different types of XAML files (it probably looks at the extension).

Comment: Just noticed it was exactly as you said :) The setting is saved file by file and not by categories like `Window`, `ResourceDictionary` etc. +1

Comment: Changing that setting would bother me more! And I agree it's just looking at the file extension, but yes... VS could be smart enough to figure it out. Cheers